# runtime error with KeyAdapter, awt, swing on java. help spot the error

Tags: java, swing, awt

hello im wrote some code i though it was going to work but it compiles and it doesnt even throws an exception or anything. it also creates the icon like its openned but i click it and it doesnt do anything please need help to know what am i doing wrong . heres the code of the class:

```
package practicagraficos8;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ventanatexto {
   public JFrame ventana;
   public String texto;
    ventanatexto(){
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    texto="";
    ventana= new JFrame("teclado");
    panel1 panel= new panel1();
    ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ventana.add(panel);
     ventana.setVisible(true);
    ventana.addKeyListener(new handler());

    }

    public class panel1 extends JPanel {

        @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
    Dimension dim= getSize();
    g.clearRect(0, 0, dim.width, dim.height);
    g.drawString(texto, WIDTH, WIDTH);
    };


}
    class handler extends KeyAdapter{
        @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k){
    char tecla= k.getKeyChar();
    switch(tecla){

        case 127:texto="";
    break;
        case 8: if(texto.length()>0){texto=texto.substring(0, texto.length()-1);}
            break;
        default:
            if (texto.length()<15){texto+=tecla;}

    }
    ventana.repaint();
    }

    }}
```

and here is my main:

```
package practicagraficos8;

public class Practicagraficos8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ventanatexto prueba= new ventanatexto();
    }
}
```

Comment: no exception in console? Even at runtime?

Comment: no there are no exceptions at all. hope you can spot the problem. thank you.

Comment: most likey your `JPanel` does not have focus, call `requestFocusInWindow()` on your `JPanel` instance after setting `JFrame` to visible and see if that works, if not double click on the `JPanel` and try again. If it works for any of the above your JPanel lost focus when it was added to `JFrame`. Rather use KeyBidnings and look at KeyEvent class the whole `case 127` is bad. Also override `paintComponent` of `JPanel` and not `paint()`

Comment: As @David notes, focus is _required_ for `KeyListener`; +1 for `KeyAdapter` (rather than `KeyListener`) and [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11924118/230513), "`drawString()` expects the coordinates to represent the [baseline](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) of the `String`."

```
FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
g.drawString(texto, 0, fm.getAscent());
```

[image: ventana]

In addition,

- Use a `JTextComponent` for editable text.
- Use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), rather than `KeyListener`.
- Use `pack()` on the enclosing `Window`.
- "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).
- Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- Use appropriate [access control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Answer (score 1):

I've tried running your code. If you ask why your window does not show up, try setting bounds (size and location) on your JFrame:

```
ventana.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
```

It seems the window will not show up, when using the decorated look and feel, if no bounds are set.

Comment: Absent an intrinsic preferred size, `setBounds()` may be appropriate, as suggested among these [caveats](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513). The essential problem is the text baseline, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13333956/230513).