# drawing in a JPanel

Tags: eclipse, swing, netbeans, java

i have my class declared:

```
public class myRightPanel extends JPanel
```

then i override the paintComponent of my super class like this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){  
        super.paintComponents(g);
                //Draw bunch of things here
}
```

Now it turns out i also need a method which takes in two integer(x,y) parameters and adds something to my already drawn `myRightPanel` at that coordinates. How do i do this when i have already overridden my `paintComponent()`?

Comment: 1) What exactly do [tag:eclipse], [tag:netbeans] & [tag:jdk] have to do with this? 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Are you ignoring my comment about the tags?

Answer (score 3):

Store the x,y as a `Point` as an attribute of the class so it is accessible within the paint method.  Call `repaint()`.

Comment: what do i call repaint on? how do i call it?

Comment: Again, a little louder this time.. ***For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).***

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Graphics object to draw any content you want.

For example:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){  
  super.paintComponents(g);
  g.drawString("Hello test", 0, 0);
}
```

I recommend reading Java 2D tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html

Comment: Absent any descenders, the text will be invisible, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2658663/230513); see also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13333956/230513).